# Javascript Lookup Read File

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not sure what the correct way to do this is.
I would like to have a look up table to quickly search for key/value.
So I made a json that looks like this:

```
{
  "k1": [
    ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"],
    ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"],
    ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"]
  ],
  "k2": [
    ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"],
    ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"],
    ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"]
  ]
}
```

There are around 20k keys each with roughly 24 arrays within array as shown above. The file is around ~8MB.

I have a function that fires onClick that needs to use the table for reference. And the function is designed to get called multiple times by multiple users. So does that mean I have to parse it each time?

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: What does this table represent? Is there any page that will use All of the table? I have a hunch you could probably split the table into alot of small pieces and have each piece only relate to the model module it's used by. Alternatively, put everything inside a database, so you don't need to keep the entire table in memory clientside. To answer the question though, each user will have to parse the JSON file into this object only once.

Comment: Thanks @Shilly I don't can't split them up. The table is a dictionary for keys that users can look for. Thanks for the tip on putting it in database, I'll look into that.